# MongoDB Querying one is simple find and another is searching same string using regex but both the result are different

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

Can anyone please explain
why these two similar query giving the different results

```
db.getCollection('inspections').find({
                "address.city": {"$regex": "NEW YORK"} }).count()
```

Result is 18303

```
db.getCollection('inspections').find({
                "address.city":  "NEW YORK" }).count()
```

Result is 18279

Comment: both the conditions are different, first query `$regex`  => regular expression capabilities for pattern matching strings in queries and  second query for equal `$eq` => will match exact same string in collection, please refer [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) , for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the nature of a regular expression.  The regex you are using /NEW YORK/ will match address.city values:

```
"NEW YORK"
"aNEW YORK"
"NEW YORKER"
"GREATER NEW YORK"
"MANHATTAN, NEW YORK"
```

Along with any other string that happens to contain those 8 characters in that order.

If you want to use a regex for an exact string match, anchor the start of the string with `^` and the end with `$`